# Incomplete definition when using struct in header file

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compilation, header

When I try to compile this program without the struct in the `functions.h` and `functions.c` file, it works. But when using a struct, it doesn't work.

How do I properly use structs with these `.h` and `.c` files?

**main.c file**

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "functions.h"

    int main(void) {
      func1();
      func2();
      //make a linked list of persons

      person * head = NULL;
      head = (person *) malloc(sizeof(person));
      if (head == NULL) {
          return 1;
      }
      head->val = 1;
      head->next = NULL;

      return 0;
    }
```

**functions.h file**

```
struct node;  
typedef struct node person;
void func1(void);
void func2(void);
```

**functions.c file**

```
 #include "functions.h"

    struct node {
        char name;
        int age;
        node *next;
    };

    void func1(void) {
        printf("Function 1!\n");
    }

    void func2(void) {
        printf("Function 2!\n");
    }
```

**Compile it with:**

**gcc -o main.exe main.c functions.c**

Comment: Define the struct directly in the header.

Comment: You need `functions.c` to `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` because only it knows the size.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use opaque types (incomplete types) when you don't need to know the size or 'contents' of the type — which means you can only use an opaque type when you only need pointers to the type.  If you need the size, as in `main()` when you try to allocate enough space for a person, then you can't use an opaque type.

Either create an allocator function in `functions.c`, declare it in `functions.h` and call it in `main.c`, or define the type in `functions.h` for use in both `main.c` and `functions.c`.

In your code, the `main()` function also accesses members of the structure (`head->val`, `head->next`), so defining the type in `functions.h` is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**Add to functions.h:**

```
typedef struct node {
        char name;
        int age;
        node *next;
    } person;
```

to the functions.h did the trick as posted by ***Jonathan Leffler!***

**Remove from functions.h file:**

```
struct node;  
typedef struct node person;
```

**Remove from functions.c file:**

```
struct node {
    char name;
    int age;
    node *next;
};
```